# How to Sum values from EditText on ListView?

Tags: android, listview, sum

I have lists of color variations of a product in the ListView . Each list color variation has an EditText. I want to try to make the validation process orders when my button clicked.

This My Code:

```
btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
            String[] listData = new String[count];
            int[] listData2 = new int[count];
            int sum = 0;
            try {
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View quantity=listView.getChildAt(i);
                if (quantity.findViewById(R.id.quantityOrder) != null){
                    EditText quantityOrder = (EditText) quantity.findViewById(R.id.quantityOrder);
                    listData[i] = quantityOrder.getText().toString();
                    listData2[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityOrder.getText().toString());  // set edittext to int
                    sum += listData2[i];
                        jsonObject.put("params_"+i,listData[i]);   // put to params for volley request

                }

               }
                if (sum < 1) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry, you need to fill Order Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  // validation input if edittext empty
                        .show();} else {   
                    Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString()); }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

        }
    });
```

My app get force close. here the error code

```
09-25 23:01:05.679  32623-32623/id.nijushop.ikutan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
        at id.nijushop.ikutan.ProductDetail$1.onClick(ProductDetail.java:150)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please, some one fix my code...I think i need to do something about this

```
quantity.findViewById(R.id.quantityOrder)// need to set to Interger
```

Comment: What is the text inside each of your `EditText` field just before it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
listData2[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityOrder.getText().toString());  // set edittext to int
```

The `Integer.parseInt(String string)` method will return an int or throw a `NumberFormatException` if passed string is not a valid integer string. An empty string - `""` doesn't make up a valid integer, so if your `EditText` is empty, the problem arises.

You need to shield the execution of `parseInt` with a try - catch block catching a `NumberFormatException` and act accordingly - abort the method or else, but you obviously cannot continue with your arithmetic if you haven't provided a valid number.

Also, the thing that would help you is, within your `EditText` element in xml file, include an `inputType` property, for example:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberSigned" />
```

This `inputType` property will cause the system to use an automatic inputFilter and provideonly numeric soft keyboard, so the user cannot enter an invalid number (in this case, only a signed integer). However this will still not account for empty input, so you'll need to either catch `NumberFormatException` or check whether string from your EditText is not empty. (`!string.isEmpty()`)